# Add generated files to link only msbuild

Tags: c++, msbuild

I have a msbuild project which runs but I want it to just link it with different options. But how can I add the obj. Of the generated c files to the linker? Msbuild does recognize but never use them

I tried to sdd the generated c files with compile, content to include. Also the additionalDependencies doesn‘t worked

Comment: Have you added the .obj file to the project and in the ['General' properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/general-property-page-file?view=msvc-170) for the file verified the 'Item Type' is set to 'Object'?

Comment: No I try do do it dynamically within a target because our it suits our Build process most

Comment: Ok. Don't add it to the `ClCompile` Item Collection. Instead add the .obj file to the `Object` Item Collection, e.g. `<ItemGroup><Object Include="example.obj" /></ItemGroup>`. Also be sure to define your target to be `BeforeTargets="Link"`. (For C++ projects there is a `Link` target that calls the `Link` task.)

Comment: Cool one step forward. Now the msbuild knows the obj. But still doesn‘t use it. I therefore checked the log file

Comment: I got it running. I have to call my target which adds the object with the AfterTarges=„ResolveReferences“. :-) Thanks a lot for your help